# Is there an alternative for faceted search in vespa?

Tags: vespa

I'm evaluating vespa, but couldn't find any reference to faceted search (https://lucidworks.com/2009/09/02/faceted-search-with-solr/) in vespa.ai documentation. Is there a similar feature in vespa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for Vespa's [grouping feature](https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/grouping.html)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we call it grouping. See https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/grouping.html & https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/reference/grouping-syntax.html